# Immersed boundary method

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to use immersed boundary method for the 3D flow problem (Navier-Stokes equations), but I'm maybe misunderstood something in this method. Main principles I took from this [book](http://ebookbrowsee.net/peskin-c-s-numerical-analysis-of-blood-flow-in-the-heart-pdf-d42966243). I use the continuous forcing approach and the quasi-rigid immersed boundary, i.e. the boundary force computed from this equation [image], where ***k*** is the stiffness, ***x ref*** is the initial node position.

My trouble is that in the first time layer I have zero boundary force (because I don't know this force) and nonzero fluid velocity. So the fluid shifts the all boundary nodes and I have something like this (this is the 3D flow around a cylinder that was projected on the Oz axis)

[image]

Because the all nodes were shifted they all have the same force including the right half circle. So the streamlines twisted through the immersed boundary (a cylinder).

How can I avoid this?

**UPD**

I have steady flow problem and maybe it's the source of troubles. I thought that the series of calculation of steady problem can approximates the unsteady and allow to use immersed boundary method, but now I'm not sure about this.

**UPD**
I have reached the more correct flow, when stiffness has been increased. I didn't understand this, because my calculation had not enough time steps.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Try rephrasing it by including formulas that describe what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I've updated my question, but the method contains a main part of formulas. What exactly I miss?

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug in your code. Are you sure your code is working correctly? What benchmark tests have you ran already? Have you tried simulating an oscillating cylinder? See http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3976 for details.

Comment: Note, the immersed boundary equations are very stiff. Furthermore, the stiffness increases as k increases. Simulating a rigid body will require a very small time step to keep the simulation stable.

Comment: I've updated my question one more time with the results of my experiments. That was not a bug, but the lack of the time steps and stiffness.